# Ruby очистка хеша

Tags: ruby, хеширование

Я записываю хеш:

```
hash[key.to_s.strip] = value.to_s.strip
```

в хеш:

```
table['Order information'] = hash
```

При очистке `hash`:

```
hash.clear
```

он очищается как сам, так и в хэше `table`.
Как мне избежать очистки `hash` в `table`, при этом очистив сам `hash`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Очевидно, это должен быть другой объект.

**Сейчас это один и тот же хэшмап.** Все, кто помнит ссылку именно на него, будут видеть происходящие в нём изменения тоже. Поэтому, если хотите обезопасить сохраняемый внутри большого хэша объект от случайных изменений, сохраните туда **копию**:

```
table['Order information'] = hash.dup
```

...и для гарантии можно **заморозить** объект, потеряв возможность вносить в него изменения:

```
table['Order information'] = hash.dup.freeze
```

---

Обратите внимание, что копирование **поверхностное**: дублируется состояние только непосредственно копируемого объекта, но не объектов, на которые он ссылается внутри. Ведёт это себя примерно так:

```
foo = {a: "ha-ha-ha"}
bar = foo.dup

# строка не является частью хэшмапа, dup скопировал лишь ссылку на неё:
# если изменить строку в одном месте, она изменится и в другом
foo[:a].tr!('a', 'o')
foo # => {a: "ho-ho-ho"} # изменился, согласно строчке выше
bar # => {a: "ho-ho-ho"} # тоже изменился, внезапно

# но какие ключи хранятся в хэшмапе, он знает сам, непосредственно
foo.delete(:a)
foo # => {}
bar # => {a: "ho-ho-ho"}
```